# How to embed two Lazy Line svg animations (Divi builder Web site)?

Tags: javascript, svg, divi

I try to play **two** lazy line animations on the same web page. The web site is made with WordPress and Divi Builder.

Here is what I made so far.

This line in the head section of the web page:

```
<script src="https://N3W-waLL.peri-ray.be/wp-content/uploads/lazy-line-painter-1.9.6.min.js"></script>
```

This code in a Divi code module (animation C):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){ 
            document.onreadystatechange = () => {

              if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                let el = document.querySelector('#activitesperi-et-ray-c');
                let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":10,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"LightGray","strokeCap":"butt"}); 
myAnimation.paint(); 
              }
            }
     })();

        </script>
<style>
    
    #activitesperi-et-ray-c {
              width: 70vw;
              height: 70vh;
              position: relative;
              overflow: visible;
            }

</style>
<svg version="1.1" id="activitesperi-et-ray-c" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 215.734 281.893" enable-background="new 0 0 215.734 281.893" xml:space="preserve" data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">
<path fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M45.439,6.863
    c5.32-3.889,11.487-2.424,11.552,4.003c0.053,5.271,0,8.965,0,9.372c0,0.583,0.488,1.058,0.83,1.058" data-llp-id="activitesperi-et-ray-c-0" data-llp-duration="1820" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style="" data-llp-stroke-cap=""/>
<path fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M56.978,13.221
    
<!-- and so on -->
</svg>
```

This code in a Divi code module (animation D, delayed):

```
          (function(){ 

            document.onreadystatechange = () => {

              if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                        
                /**
                 * Setup your Lazy Line element.
                 * see README file for more settings
                 */

                let el = document.querySelector('#activitesperi-et-ray-d');
                let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":0.6,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#000000","strokeCap":"butt","delay":2010}); 
                myAnimation.paint(); 
              }
            }

          })();

        </script>
<style>#activitesperi-et-ray-d {
              width: 70vw;
              height: 70vh;
              position: relative;
              overflow: visible;
            }
</style>
        <svg version="1.1" id="activitesperi-et-ray-d" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 215.734 281.893" enable-background="new 0 0 215.734 281.893" xml:space="preserve" data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">
<path fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M45.439,6.863
    
<!-- and so on… -->

</svg>
```

Here is the web on which I tested : [My Test Page](https://n3w-wall.peri-ray.be/test-svg-superposes-1321dsf6g54/)

Please note:

- Each animation works fine separately.
- When two animations are embedded, only the second one is visible.
- What I would like: two animations, one over the other.

Comment: These two links give how to's but I don't know how to apply them in my site: 
[link](http://web.simmons.edu/~grovesd/comm328/modules/svg/lazy-line-painter) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665217/how-can-i-animate-two-jquery-lazy-line-painter-animations-one-after-the-other)

Answer (score -1):

It's OK. I made one SVG with two and styled both parts with CSS class

```
<!-- css  -->
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #333333;
    }
    
    #activitesperi-et-ray-c {
        width: 70vw;
        height: 70vh;
        position: relative;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    
    .lignefine {
        stroke: white;
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 0.5;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        fill-opacity: 0;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        animation-delay: 1820ms;
    }
    
    .lignegrasse {
        stroke: #87dd25;
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: 10;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        fill-opacity: 0;
        stroke-linecap: butt;
        animation-delay: 0s;
    }
</style>

<!-- Include lazylinepainter -->
<script src="lazy-line-painter-1.9.6.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {

        document.onreadystatechange = () => {

            if (document.readyState === 'complete') {

                /**
                 * Setup your Lazy Line element.
                 * see README file for more settings
                 */

                let el = document.querySelector('#activitesperi-et-ray-c');
                let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {
                    "ease": "easeLinear",
                    "strokeOpacity": 1,

                });
                myAnimation.paint();
            }
        }

    })();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- removed from svg header: enable-background="new 0 0 215.734 281.893" -->
<svg version="1.1" id="activitesperi-et-ray-c"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 215.734 281.893" xml:space="preserve" data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">

<!-- here begins svg with thick lines -->  
<path class="lignegrasse" d="M45.439,6.863&#10;&#9;c5.32-3.889,11.487-2.424,11.552,4.003c0.053,5.271,0,8.965,0,9.372c0,0.583,0.488,1.058,0.83,1.058" data-llp-id="activitesperi-et-ray-c-200" data-llp-duration="1820" />
<path class="lignegrasse" d="M56.978,13.221&#10;&#9;c-11.959-3.472-13.96,2.656-11.762,6.122c2.903,4.579,11.756,1.143,11.792-2.43" data-llp-id="activitesperi-et-ray-c-201" data-llp-duration="1820" />

<!-- etc. etc. -->
<!-- end of thick lines -->

<!-- here begins svg with thin lines -->
<path class="lignefine" d="M45.439,6.863&#10;&#9;c5.32-3.889,11.487-2.424,11.552,4.003c0.053,5.271,0,8.965,0,9.372c0,0.583,0.488,1.058,0.83,1.058" data-llp-id="activitesperi-et-ray-c-0" data-llp-duration="1820" data-llp-delay="1820" />
<path class="lignefine" d="M56.978,13.221&#10;&#9;c-11.959-3.472-13.96,2.656-11.762,6.122c2.903,4.579,11.756,1.143,11.792-2.43" data-llp-id="activitesperi-et-ray-c-1" data-llp-duration="1820" data-llp-delay="1820" />
<!-- etc. etc. -->
<!-- end of thin lines -->
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30841582)

Comment: It's done. I hope you'll vote up :)